# How to connect camcorder to Ubuntu via HDMI

Tags: video, hdmi

My camcorder Panasonic includes an HDMI cable. Is there any software I can use to play the videos to my laptop via HDMI port? My system is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The software here is only a half of the solution. The HDMI on laptop is only output, but you need input.

So you need to get USB video capture device first.
Like [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/32894357692.html) for example. I have tested it in Ubuntu, it works.

Then use gUVCview or VLC Player to view the stream, [OBS Studio](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio) to record it multiplex.

Answer (score 0):

Join one end of the HDMI cable to the camcorder HDMI output and the opposite end of the cable to the HDMI input of the video capture device. Connect the video capture device to the computer using the USB cable. Turn on the camcorder by moving the POWER switch to the CAMERA position.